# Insertar imagen ubicada fuera de carpeta pública en etiqueta img de HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Tengo un problema, en una etiqueta img incrustada en un HTML, para asignarle una imagen que se encuentre dentro de la carpeta pública basta con asignar la ruta al src, el problema lo encuentro cuando intento asignar una imagen que se encuentra fuera de la carpeta pública, y por lo tanto no es posible acceder vía URL, existe alguna forma de hacerlo? quiero pensar que con PHP es posible pero no encuentro la vía idonea, espero me puedan orientar, muchas gracias.

```
<img src="cómo vinculo una imagen que se encuentra fuera de la carpeta public?">
```

Las etiquetas img las crearé mediante javascript.
Utilizo Nginx, PHP 7.

Answer (score 1):

## Opción 1: Symlinks

Lo siguiente no es una solución general, pero si tu estructura de archivos fuese

```
|_app
  |_imagen.png
  |_controllers
  |_models
  |_routes
  |_public
    |_css
    |_js
    |_img
    |_index.html
```

Y tu root, configurado en nginx, apuntase a **app/public**, para mostrar `imagen.png` que está un directorio más arriba, podrías pararte en public y hacer

```
ln -s ../imagen.png
```

Con lo cual podrías mostrarla como si estuviera en public

```
 <img src="/imagen.png">
```

Es decir, crear un link simbólico. Si estás trabajando con control de versiones (e.g. git) el link simbólico se puede añadir a control de versiones y conserva su condición de link, no es convertido implícitamente en una copia del archivo (como hace, por ejemplo, Dropbox).

Como dije al principio, no es una solución general porque si tienes más de una imagen y quieres hacer lo mismo, tendrías que hacerlo una por una. **A menos que...** metas esas imágenes en un directorio

```
|_app
  |_no_public_pero_quiero_mostrarlos
    |_imagen1.png
    |_imagen2.png
  |_controllers
  |_models
  |_routes
  |_public
    |_css
    |_js
    |_img
    |_index.html
```

Luego haciendo

```
  ln -s ../no_public_pero_quiero_mostrarlos
```

Podrías mostrar tus imágenes como

```
 <img src="/no_public_pero_quiero_mostrarlos/imagen.png">
```

## Opción 2: Usando PHP

PHP puede leer del sistema de archivos libremente independiente de la carpeta que exponga nginx. De manera que podrías tener un archivo `imagen1.php` que contuviese

```
<?php

$imgpath = __DIR__ . '/../imagen1.png';
$imginfo = getimagesize($imgpath);
$mimetype = $imginfo['mime'];
header('Content-type: ' . $mimetype);
readfile($imgpath);
```

Si te fijas:

- Estoy declarando la ruta absoluta a la imagen que quiero desplegar
- Usando la función [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) no sólo obtengo sus dimensiones sino su tipo (en este caso, png)
- Con el tipo mime puedo enviar el header `Content-type: image/png` que el browser necesita para saber que es una imagen
- Usando [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) mando a la salida (en este caso, al frontend) lo que leí del archivo sin pasar por memoria. Si es un archivo grande, es más eficiente. Si quisieras reprocesar la imagen, ahí tendrías que leerla con [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) primero.

Con esto podrías mostrar tu imagen usando

```
 <img src="/imagen1.php">
```

De nuevo, esto es una solución particular. Tendrías que inventar una convención para decirle a ese script qué imagen quieres leer, pero en ese caso también tendrías que cuidarte de que eso abra la puerta a que un tercero lea información de otro archivo, de manera que usar algo como

muestraimagen.php?imagen=imagen1.png

Esta solución es harto peligrosa, no me gusta para nada.

## Opción 3: Nginx

Tal vez la manera correcta de hacerlo sería usar una regla de reescritura de nginx tal que, **para archivos de tipo imagen**, si no los encuentra en public los busque en la carpeta superior.

Supongamos que en tu virtualhost tienes algo como

```
    root /var/www/proyecto/public

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_pass php;
    }
```

(probablemente no es igual, pero en este caso es irrelevante)

Si le pones una regla específica para ciertas extensiones, esa regla tiene prioridad sobre `location /` (a más específica, más prioridad). De manera que puedes cambiar lo de arriba y meter dos reglas en medio:

```
    root /var/www/proyecto/public

    location ~ \.(png|jpg|gif)$ {
            try_files $uri @parent_folder;
    }

    location @parent_folder {
            root /var/www/proyecto;
            try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_pass php;
    }
```

Ahora los archivos de tipo imagen, si no están en `public` gatillan una regla de reescritura que redeclara el `root`. Si tampoco están en el root, entonces tira 404.

## Opción 4: convertir la imagen en DataURI

Esto puede ser una mala idea si trabajas con imágenes muy grandes, pero si quieres que la imagen se muestre y sin embargo no sea accesible linkeando a tu sitio (hotlink) lo que puedes hacer es leerla de la carpeta no pública, y presentarla como [DataURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Datos_URIs).

```
<?php

$imgpath   = __DIR__ . '/../wear-black-on.png';
$imginfo   = getimagesize($imgpath);
$mimetype  = $imginfo['mime'];
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($imgpath));

$src = 'data:' . $mimetype . ';base64,' . $imageData;

echo '<p>La siguiente imagen no se puede acceder públicamente</p>';
echo '<img alt="wear-black-on" src="' . $src . '">';

echo '<p>Pero la estoy mostrando como DataURI</p>';
```

Puedes verlo funcionando en https://examples.ffflabs.com/imagen_b64.php

---

**Reflexión final**

Ten presente que sea cual sea el método que uses, siempre que el browser pueda desplegar una imagen el usuario podrá descargarla, eso sí que no hay cómo evitarlo ni siquiera usando un canvas.

Comment: Ya logré hacerlo, puse mi imagen fuera de public_html, exactamente en la carpeta principal de mi proyecto y funcionó, el problema es que ahora me deja acceder vía url y es lo que deseo evitar. Hay alguna forma?

Comment: Uh... si una etiqueta <img> puede cargar la imagen, significa que el browser puede leerla, y por transitividad cualquier persona que esté al otro lado del browser puede hacer lo mismo. Te dejé una opción que muestra la imagen como DataURI cosa que no te puedan hacer un hotlink, pero eso es todo lo que se puede hacer